# How to correctly send long string of json array using ultrasonic sound using Chirp IO?

Tags: react-native, payload

I want to send a long string using chirp io over the ultrasonic sound. I tried to break the string into 8 bytes and using for loop I am sending it but I receive only last part. How to break the string according to maxPayloadLengt and send the full string?

```
String identifier = "hello how are you, make a string";

long maxPayloadLength = chirpConnect.maxPayloadLength();

String[] str=SplitStringByByteLength(identifier,"UTF-8",8);
// it will break string into 8 bytes chunks
for(int i=0; i<str.length;i++){ 
    byte[] payload = str[i].getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    if (maxPayloadLength < payload.length) {
         break;
    } else {
       ChirpError error = chirpConnect.send(payload);

       if (error.getCode() > 0) {
               Log.e("ChirpError: ", error.getMessage());
       } else {
               Log.v("ChirpSDK: ", "Sent " + identifier);
       }
   }
}
```